# how to get ride of 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python

```py
def main():
    sample_list = []
    total = 0
    for i in range(4):
        sample_list.append(i)
        print('Enter number ', i + 1 , ' of 20', ': ', sep='', end='')
        i = float(input())
        total += i
        avg = total / i
    print(avg)
    print(total)
    print(min(i))
   


main()
```

I want the out put of min/max but I got this error

```
in main
print(min(i))
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

It doesn't let me print the min/max of the input

Comment: You are using `i` twice: for your input and as the iteration variable.

Comment: Please go through [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min), `min` requires a `sequence`

Comment: Are you trying to get 4 inputs and then finding the min?

Comment: There are multiple issues. You want to append numbers from the user in `sample_list`, not `i`. Also note, you don't want to use `i` to store user input. Finlay you want to use `sample_list` as argument for `min()`. Also to calculate mean/average you can use again `sample_list` instead of calculating inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to get `minimum` value of a `float` whereas `min()` requires a sequence.i.e, you can get the `min` value of your `sample_list` not the `float` itself.

Answer (score 0):

The `min` function is python requires to sequence to iterate through. A possible solution will be to store all the values of `i` in a list or a tuple (as you have done in `sample_list`) and then use the `min` function to find the minimum value of i

```
def main():
    sample_list = []
    total = 0
    for i in range(4):
        sample_list.append(i)
        print('Enter number ', i + 1 , ' of 20', ': ', sep='', end='')
        i = float(input())
        total += i
        avg = total / i
print(avg)
print(total)

## changed code
print(min(sample_list))
##
```